# How to get Salesforce Oauth response?

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I followed a tutorial to send a access token request to Salesforce. But I don't know how to get the response. My code below:

```
    String baseUrl = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token";

    PostMethod method = new PostMethod(baseUrl);

    HttpMethodParams params = new HttpMethodParams();

    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    content.append("grant_type=password");
    content.append("&client_id=3MVG9Y6d_Btp4xp7iNInduj8sD72efFl1ge.T8VS9JGJGrWqlNQt2mdP5qFzUdIay56PHFWSO65aFnYLhpTS_");
    content.append("&client_secret=4522939082487299040");
    content.append("&username=vuong.tran@enclave.vn");
    content.append("&password=vuong92dnKk2VykEJnVfj5Dps0as9XmRFV");

    method.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(content.toString(), "text/plain", "UTF-8"));
    method.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.executeMethod(method);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After executing

```
client.executeMethod(method);
```

you can get the response from the `PostMethod` object that you passed as an argument, for example:

```
String response = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod.html#getResponseBodyAsString()).

Comment: Thank you very much. It run well. Can I ask one more question. Now I got the response, so how can I get the sessionID from SFDC?

Comment: As far as the sessionID goes, it would probably be best to ask a new question on SO.